# How can I unit test JavaScript that will executed after the CSS transitionEnd event

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, qunit, sinon

I have bootstrap modal window. Using qunit+sinonjs (fake timers), one element stays on page (`div class='modal-backdor'`):

- http://jsfiddle.net/valuks/8xVCR/2/embedded/result/
- http://jsfiddle.net/valuks/8xVCR/2/

Look at [twitter-bootstrap (line 95)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v1.4.0/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L95), there is a transitionEnd event fired. How can I test code that will be executed after the event was fired?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this.clock.tick(1000);` dont let your test code wait for 1000ms but call all JavaScript `setTimeouts` that should happend in this time. So in your case, starting an animation, the `this.clock.tick(1000);` will have no effect cause the animation will still last 1000ms. You're looking for something like Jasmines [`waits()`](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs), which stop the execution of all test code beneath for the passed time. Seems there is no equivalent in qunit and sinon.

Btw. what you're trying to do is more a acceptance test then a unit test. You should thing about [mocking your DOM element](http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html)  so you can just trigger the transitionEnd event in your test instead of starting a real animation. Also starting an animation and wait will end in really long running unit test. So in my latest project we have about 200 test cases that will run a 1-2 seconds. So think about how long this will take when you start using `waits` in your test.